# Ошибка в цикле вывода дочерних страниц wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, друзья подскажите по такой ситуации. Делаю натяжку верстки, и на одной из страниц выводятся дочерние страницы. (на странице факультет выводятся все кафедры). В чем сложность. В верстке  наименование классов кафедры прописано div class=name-1, name-2 и т.д.
вот такой цикл у меня.

```html
 <?php
$page_children = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID()

  )
);


if($page_children->have_posts()) :
  for ($i=0; $i++<8;)
  while($page_children->have_posts()): $page_children->the_post();
  echo '<div class="facultie-'.$i.'"><a><span class="facultie__box"><a>'.get_the_title().'</a></span></a></div>';
  echo '';
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

И на выходе я получаю то что в каждом  div накладываются все кафедры.
как вывести чтобы была только одна кафедра в блоке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть мнение, что дело в неправильно оформленном цикле `for`. Попробуйте так:

```html
<?
$page_children = get_posts([
  'numberposts'=>-1,
  'post_type'=>'page',
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID()
]);

foreach($page_children as $index=>$post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
  echo '<div class="facultie-'.($index+1).'"><a href="#"><span class="facultie__box">'.get_the_title().'</span></a></div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Да, заработало, спасибо!! 
только начинает присваивать с нуля. Как это исправить?

Comment: Добавлять к индексу единицу, очевидно

Comment: Круто! Спасибо огромное!! Выручили.